# Uploading Facebook Profile Image to S3 via aws ios sdk

Tags: ios, facebook, amazon-s3, awss3transfermanager

I want the profile picture of users uploaded to my S3 bucket when they register with my app.

Do I need to download the picture first from facebook, or can I pass the external url to the AWSS3TransferManager? PReferable I would of course like to not have to download the picture first to the client's devise and only then upload to S3.

```
//We create the url to the FB Profile Picture
    NSString *compURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/FACEBOOKID/picture?type=large"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:compURLString];
    // We download the FB Profile Picture from Facebook TBD DO WE NEED THIS STEP OR IS IT POSSIBLE TO PASS THE EXTERNAL URL? AND NOT DOWNLOAD THE IMAGE FIRST? https://graph.facebook.com/FACEBOOKID/picture?type=large TO THE AWS UPLOAD MANAGER
    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadPhotoTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession]
                                                   downloadTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSURL *location, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                                       UIImage 

                                   // NOw that we have the FB Profile Picture, we upload it to S3
        AWSS3TransferManager *uploadManager = [AWSS3TransferManager defaultS3TransferManager];

        NSString *const S3BucketName = @"DEMO";

       //upload the image
       AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest *uploadRequest = [AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest new];
       uploadRequest.body = location;
       uploadRequest.bucket = S3BucketName;
       uploadRequest.key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"@%.jpg", facebookID];
       uploadRequest.contentType = @"image/jpg";

       [[uploadManager upload:uploadRequest] continueWithExecutor:[AWSExecutor mainThreadExecutor]
                                                     withBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {...
                                                   }];

    [downloadPhotoTask resume];}
```